# .NET Maui Indeterminite Progress Bar

Tags: c#, .net, maui

I am using .NET MAUI to build a cross platform desktop application.

I have a lengthy event for which I would like to show an indeterminate progress bar (like the one seen [here](https://material.io/components/progress-indicators#linear-progress-indicators)) so the user can see that the operation is running without a known end.

I am familiar with the MAUI progressbar element and how to animate known progress as shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/progressbar).

```
await progressBar.ProgressTo(0.75, 500, Easing.Linear);
```

However, there doesn't seem to be a native way of growing and shrinking the bar without animating from 0-100 and back again. When animating in this manner, I have to fill the entire bar and animate back to 0. I am not able to animate between a range (25% - 50% for instance).

Is there a way to achieve an indeterminate progress bar in a MAUI app?

Comment: After some research, it seems that the MAUI platform separates determinate and indeterminate progress between progressbar and activityindicator respectively. The activityindicator element shows a lengthy operation is taking place in the form of a circular animation. For the time being, activityindicator may be the only way to achieve indeterminate progress, albeit in a different format than progressbar.

Comment: you could easily layer two BoxViews on top of each other and animate them to achieve a similar effect

Answer (score 3):

I have just published a ProgressBar package on nuget.org that can be used for your purposes. It works with .NET MAUI Desktop applications as well as mobile apps.

Repo: https://github.com/ewerspej/epj.ProgressBar.Maui

Nuget: https://www.nuget.org/packages/epj.ProgressBar.Maui

<s>It's still a pre-release, but you can try it out, if you like.</s>

You would have to implement the animation according to your own needs, but you can definitely use animations to create something like an indeterminate state.

**XAML**

You need to set `UseRange = true` for this to work.

```xml
<maui:ProgressBar
    x:Name="AnimatedProgressBar"
    HeightRequest="5"
    Margin="15,0"
    UseRange="True"
    UseGradient="True"
    ProgressColor="Blue"
    GradientColor="Orange"/>
```

**Code**

```cs
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BindingContext = this;

    var lowerAnimation = new Animation(v => AnimatedProgressBar.LowerRangeValue = (float)v, -0.4, 1.0);
    var upperAnimation = new Animation(v => AnimatedProgressBar.UpperRangeValue = (float)v, 0.0, 1.4);

    lowerAnimation.Commit(this, "lower", length: 1000, easing: Easing.CubicInOut, repeat: () => true);
    upperAnimation.Commit(this, "upper", length: 1000, easing: Easing.CubicInOut, repeat: () => true);
}
```